# Merge XDocuments by XAttribute's value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I already managed to merge `XElement`-s which have the same `XAttribute` value, but I can't figure out how to find the `List<XElement>` which are not in the appended `XDocument`.

```
<!--xml1-->
<SecurityPrivileges>
  <SecurityPrivilege Principal="user1">
    <Privilege Type="FileSystem" AccessType="read" Action="Add">c:\log</Privilege>
  </SecurityPrivilege>
</SecurityPrivileges>

<!--xml2-->
<SecurityPrivileges>
  <SecurityPrivilege Principal="user2">
    <Privilege Type="FileSystem" AccessType="read" Action="Add">c:\log</Privilege>
  </SecurityPrivilege>
</SecurityPrivileges>

<!--expected result-->
<SecurityPrivileges>
  <SecurityPrivilege Principal="user1">
    <Privilege Type="FileSystem" AccessType="read" Action="Add">c:\log</Privilege>
  </SecurityPrivilege>
  <SecurityPrivilege Principal="user2">
    <Privilege Type="FileSystem" AccessType="read" Action="Add">c:\log</Privilege>
  </SecurityPrivilege>
</SecurityPrivileges>
```

And here is my incomplete method. I merge the principals and check if a Privilege is already there or not, but I can't figure out how to append new principals to `result`.

```
internal XDocument AppendXml(XDocument original, XDocument append)
{
    XDocument result = XDocument.Parse($"<{root}></{root}>");

    //Find similar principals
    foreach (XElement originalElement in original.Root.Elements())
    {
        XElement resultElement = originalElement;
        string originalPrincipal = originalElement.Attribute(PRINCIPAL).Value;

        //Matching principal in the append xml - there can be only one
        XElement appendPrincipal = append.Root.Elements().Where(x =>
            x.Attribute(PRINCIPAL).Value.Equals(originalPrincipal)).ElementAt(0);

        if (!appendPrincipal.IsEmpty)
        {
            foreach (XElement appendPrivilege in appendPrincipal.Elements())
            {
                //Check if Privilege appending is necessary
                if (!originalElement.Elements()
                     .Any(oPrivilege => HasPrivilege(oPrivilege, appendPrivilege)))
                {
                    resultElement.Add(appendPrivilege);
                }
            }
        }
        result.Root.Add(resultElement);
    }

    //TODO add new principals to result
    List<XElement> appendPrincipals = append.Root.Elements().Where(...);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: suggest convert xml to a dictionary, merge data in dictionary and convert back to xml as output.

Comment: @qxg I would prefer to keep it as an XDocument. I have a dictionary conversion earlier during the process, and I would not like to convert it again.

Comment: Is it possible merge them when they are still dictionary.

Comment: @qxg Unfortunately no. It is a different step and in a different stage.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It is not as easy to read as I intended...

```
foreach (XElement appendElement in append.Root.Elements())
{
    string appendPrincipal = appendElement.Attribute(PRINCIPAL).Value;
    //If the result does not contain an XElement with this attribute
    if (!result.Root.Elements()
         .Any(x => x.Attribute(PRINCIPAL).Value.Equals(appendPrincipal)))
    {
        result.Root.Add(appendElement);
    }
}
```